# Converting JSON API results to a dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

I've connected to the API and got a response but having trouble converting the Json into a dataframe so i can work with it in Python. Can you help pls? or show me a different way to convert JSON response to a dataframe pls

```
   import json

def jprint(obj):
    # create a formatted string of the Python JSON object
    text = json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4)
    print(text)

jprint(response.json())
```

**First result as an example of the JSON response**

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "age": 26,
        "appearances_away": 8,
        "appearances_home": 9,
        "appearances_overall": 17,
        "assists_away": 0,
        "assists_home": 0,
        "assists_overall": 0,
        "assists_per_90_overall": 0,
        "birthday": 805075200,
        "cards_overall": 0,
        "cards_per_90_overall": 0,
        "clean_sheets_away": 2,
        "clean_sheets_home": 3,
        "clean_sheets_overall": 5,
        "clean_sheets_per_overall": 28,
        "club_team_2_id": -1,
        "club_team_id": 268,
        "competition_id": 6015,
        "conceded_away": 9,
        "conceded_home": 8,
        "conceded_overall": 17,
        "conceded_per_90_overall": 1,
        "continent": "eu",
        "ending_year": 2022,
        "first_name": "Cameron",
        "full_name": "Cameron Dawson",
        "goals_away": 0,
        "goals_home": 0,
        "goals_involved_per_90_overall": 0,
        "goals_overall": 0,
        "goals_per_90_away": 0,
        "goals_per_90_home": 0,
        "goals_per_90_overall": 0,
        "height": 183,
        "id": 7572,
        "known_as": "Cameron Dawson",
        "last_match_timestamp": 1637420400,
        "last_name": "Dawson",
        "league": "EFL League Two",
        "league_type": "Domestic League",
        "min_per_assist_overall": 0,
        "min_per_card_overall": 0,
        "min_per_conceded_overall": 90,
        "min_per_goal_overall": 0,
        "min_per_match": 90,
        "minutes_played_away": 720,
        "minutes_played_home": 810,
        "minutes_played_overall": 1530,
        "national_team_id": -1,
        "nationality": "England",
        "penalty_goals": 0,
        "penalty_misses": 0,
        "penalty_success": -1,
        "position": "Goalkeeper",
        "rank_in_club_top_scorer": 15,
        "rank_in_league_top_attackers": 225,
        "rank_in_league_top_defenders": 53,
        "rank_in_league_top_midfielders": 268,
        "red_cards_overall": 0,
        "season": "2021/2022",
        "shorthand": "cameron-dawson",
        "starting_year": 2021,
        "url": "https://footystats.org/players/england/cameron-dawson",
        "weight": 69,
        "yellow_cards_overall": 0
    },
    {
        "age": 33,
        "appearances_away": 1,
        "appearances_home": 3,
        "appearances_overall": 4,
        "assists_away": 0,
        "assists_home": 1,
        "assists_overall": 1,
        "assists_per_90_overall": 0.38,
        "birthday": 570758400,
        "cards_overall": 3,
        "cards_per_90_overall": 1.15,
        "clean_sheets_away": 0,
```

**Attempt to create dataframe with results**

```
   from pandas import json_normalize 

df = json_normalize(response, 'abc')
print (df)
```

**Error message**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-52c0f6dce382> in <module>
      1 from pandas import json_normalize
      2 
----> 3 df = json_normalize(response, 'abc')
      4 print (df)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _json_normalize(data, record_path, meta, meta_prefix, record_prefix, errors, sep, max_level)
    334                 records.extend(recs)
    335 
--> 336     _recursive_extract(data, record_path, {}, level=0)
    337 
    338     result = DataFrame(records)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _recursive_extract(data, path, seen_meta, level)
    307         else:
    308             for obj in data:
--> 309                 recs = _pull_records(obj, path[0])
    310                 recs = [
    311                     nested_to_record(r, sep=sep, max_level=max_level)

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _pull_records(js, spec)
    246         if has non iterable value.
    247         """
--> 248         result = _pull_field(js, spec)
    249 
    250         # GH 31507 GH 30145, GH 26284 if result is not list, raise TypeError if not

/srv/conda/envs/notebook/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/json/_normalize.py in _pull_field(js, spec)
    237                 result = result[field]
    238         else:
--> 239             result = result[spec]
    240         return result
    241 

TypeError: byte indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Where does that `abc` key come from?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(response.json()['data'])
```

Comment: Thanks will try that :)

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Comment: I'm having trouble on another issue, do you know how to extract the stats pls? I've managed to get the rest of the data into rows in a data frame but the stats is a blob in one column (stats) still, thanks!

Comment: {
    "data": [
        {
            "alt_names": [
                "The Clarets"
            ],
            "competition_id": -1,
            "continent": null,
            "country": "England",
            "english_name": "Burnley FC",
            "founded": "1882",
            "full_name": "Burnley FC",
            "id": 145,
            "image": "https://cdn.footystats.org/img/teams/england-burnley-fc.png",
            "last_updated_match_timestamp": 1639317600,
            "last_x_home_away_or_overall": "0",
            "last_x_match_num": 5,

Comment: "name": "Burnley",
            "official_sites": [
                "https://www.burnleyfootballclub.com/"
            ],
            "performance_rank": 0,
            "risk": 60,
            "season": "2021",
            "season_format": "Domestic League",
            "stats": {
                "AVGHT_away": 0.67,
                "AVGHT_home": 2.5,
                "AVGHT_overall": 1.4,
                "AVG_2hg_away": 0.33,
                "AVG_2hg_home": 0.5,